# How can I send some data like auth token from a web app to an electron thin client. I am using custom url protocols to open the thin client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, electron, ipc

How does apps like teams and zoom have a pop when we click on a meeting link in the browser that do we want to continue in the browser or open in app, if we click open in app then it launches the app in desktop and call starts on that. I want to make a similar functionality using a nextjs web app and an electron thin client.

I have built an electron thin client which launches from the browser using a custom url protocol now I want to transfer data from the next js app to electron window when I send the open in app command from the browser. Nextjs and electron are seperate apps

Answer (score 0):

In main process, register open handlers:

```js
  // Open handlers must be added as early as possible
  app.on('open-file', onOpen)
  app.on('open-url', onOpen)

  //...

  app.once('ipcReady', function () {
    processArgv(argv)
```

You can do whatever you want with that, for example redirect it to program arguments to reuse the processing parameters:

```js
function onOpen (e, torrentId) {
  e.preventDefault()

  if (app.ipcReady) {
    // Magnet links opened from Chrome won't focus the app without a setTimeout.
    // The confirmation dialog Chrome shows causes Chrome to steal back the focus.
    // Electron issue: https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/4338
    setTimeout(() => windows.main.show(), 100)

    processArgv([ torrentId ])
  } else {
    argv.push(torrentId) // [to be handled by `processArgv` later anyway]
  }
}
```

*Example sourced from WebTorrent Desktop code base: https://github.com/mathiasvr/webtorrent-desktop/blob/master/src/main/index.js#L55*

and install your app as default protocol handler in the system:

*Example sourced from WebTorrent Desktop code base:  https://github.com/mathiasvr/webtorrent-desktop/blob/master/src/main/handlers.js*